# if I have 100 numbers, and 2 lists each with a certain number of random numbers from the set of 100. How can I tell what the overlap should be.

Tags: probability

To clarify, say I have 100 numbers.

group 1 has a random 30 out of those 100 numbers.

group 2 has a random 50 out of those SAME 100 numbers.

Is there a way to tell how many numbers should overlap?

(The 30 and 50 are just examples. Hopefully, there's a formula where I'd be able to swap out those numbers for others).

Comment: What's the probability that a given number is in group $1$?  What's the probability that it is in group $2$?   As these are independent events (I am assuming) the probability that it is in both groups is just the product of the two probabilities.

Comment: There cannot be a certain number as an answer. At best you can obtain a probability for any given number of overlapping numbers (or - if such detailed information is not required - the corresponding expected value).

Comment: To clarify is also the queston whether the numbers are drawn with or without replacement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected overlap under the assumption of independent random selection can be computed from the simple proportions selected by each group.

In your example, Group 1 consists of a random 30% of the cohort, so it's therefore expected to contain 30% of Group 2 (since we assume Group 2 is independently randomly selected from the cohort at large) - the expected overlap is 30% of 50% of 100, or 15 samples.

You can also compute this the other way, reasoning that Group 2 is a random 50% of the cohort, and therefore is expected to contain 50% of Group 1. The expected overlap is 50% of 30% of the samples, yielding the same answer of 15 samples.

This number represents the expected, most likely size of the overlap, but it's actually unlikely to find exactly 15 samples overlapping due to random variation. Seeing 14 or 16 samples overlapping would also be reasonably likely. One could perform a hypothesis test to determine the size of overlap that would be deemed too unlikely to occur by chance. If you see that both groups overlap perfectly or not at all, for example, it's highly unlikely that the null hypothesis that the groups were selected randomly and independently from one another is true. To perform such a test, you'd use the *hypergeometric test*, which requires four data points - the size of Group 1, the size of Group 2, the size of the overlap, and the size of total cohort from which the groups are selected.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. I wasn't sure if it was as simple at taking 30% of the 50% or vice versa, but that makes total sense. Thanks!